# How do I reverse and select elements from a tuple in Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x

I need to create a function that takes a tuple with an even number of elements as an argument. The function should return every 2nd element in the reverse order.

so if the function was passed the following parameter:

```
t = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

It should return the following tuple:

```
t = (9,7,5,3,1)
```

I have tried the following:

```
t = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
t2 = t[::-1]
```

Which reverses the tuple, but I am not sure how to get every 2nd element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you can do it using just one slice:

```
>>> t = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
>>> t2 = t[-1::-2]
>>> t2
>>> (9, 7, 5, 3, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you that has solved my problem. Is the -2 in your second line the step value?

Comment: @JamesJameson Yes it is, two steps backwards.